# failure to deploy by django webapp on heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku-postgres

Good day, I'm trying to deploy by django webapp on heroku but i'm facing the following problem.

```
   The conflict is caused by:
       The user requested botocore==1.23.50
       awsebcli 3.20.3 depends on botocore<1.24.0 and >1.23.41
       boto3 1.26.59 depends on botocore<1.30.0 and >=1.29.59
   
   To fix this you could try to:
   1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
   2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict
   
   ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts
```

!     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
!     Push failed

And my requirement.txt is the following...

```
asgiref==3.6.0
awsebcli==3.20.3
boto3==1.26.59
botocore==1.23.50
cement==2.8.2
certifi==2022.12.7
charset-normalizer==2.0.12
colorama==0.4.3
contourpy==1.0.7
cycler==0.11.0
distlib==0.3.6
dj-database-url==1.2.0
Django==4.1.4
django-crispy-forms==2.0
django-heroku==0.3.1
django-storages==1.13.2
filelock==3.9.0
fonttools==4.38.0
future==0.16.0
gunicorn==20.1.0
idna==3.4
jmespath==0.10.0
kiwisolver==1.4.4
matplotlib==3.6.3
numpy==1.24.1
packaging==23.0
pathspec==0.9.0
Pillow==9.4.0
platformdirs==2.6.2
psycopg2==2.9.5
psycopg2-binary==2.9.5
pyparsing==3.0.9
python-dateutil==2.8.2
PyYAML==5.4.1
requests==2.26.0
s3transfer==0.6.0
semantic-version==2.8.5
six==1.14.0
sqlparse==0.4.3
termcolor==1.1.0
tzdata==2022.7
urllib3==1.26.14
virtualenv==20.17.1
wcwidth==0.1.9
whitenoise==6.4.0
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

You could upgrade your awsebcli version to 3.20.4 (2023-02-27).

From the [changelog](https://pypi.org/project/awsebcli/),

> awsebcli 3.20.4 (2023-02-27)
> Updated botocore requirement to >1.23.41,<1.29.81

This should allow you to use your current versions of boto3 and botocore. Hope it helps.